# ext js 4 column chart bug? series remain visible when I hide them

Tags: extjs, charts, hide

Feeling I had not enough control over the chart if I had used a grouped column chart, I made my own version by just adding different series to the chart. After all the store, the number of series, their colors and such all need to be set dynamically and not hard coded. So basically this is what I have:

```
chart = Ext.create("Ext.chart.Chart", {
     store: dataStore,
     axes: dynamicAxes,
     series: series
});
```

I leave out the not interesting stuff such as width, height of the chart etc.
now I have a method whichs returns a series object. This is added to the series array mentioned in the code above. The function has a "item" object parameter and also an idx param which is the index of the item object from the array it comes from, and a max param which is the size of the item array

the function returns something like this:

```
var w = (typeof (max) !== "undefined" && max !== null) ? this._getWidthByMax(max) : 30;
return {
         type: "column",
         axis = "left",
         xField = "timestamp",
         yField = item.id, // store field name equals the id of the item object
         style = { stroke: colorCode, "stroke-width": (item.isDefault) ? 2 : 1,   fill: colorCode },
         width = w, 
         renderer = function (sprite, rec, attr, bix) {
            var nx = idx * w;
            return Ext.apply(attr, { translation: { x: nx} });
         }
     }
```

now this works fine for the number of columns I want to have. That can be one, two, three... up to seven currently. 
However, if I want to hide a series, the following call doesn't work:

```
chart.series.getAt(idx).hideAll();
```

while it does work if I render my chart as a line chart. 
is this a bug in Ext-js 4 or is it because of how I rendered the series for my column chart?

Comment: is there anybody who has an idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since nobody has replied to my question and I have found a solution in the meantime, I might as well answer my own question...

the problem occurred in Ext Js 4.0.7. 
With version 4.1 RC 2 the hideAll behaved correctly.

So the solution, for anyone who would have the same problem, is to upgrade to 4.1 RC 2 or newer.